# How can I ensure correct playback orientation of recorded video?

Tags: android, video, orientation, video-capture, android-video-player

I'm using the [`MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-video) intent to capture video and later play it back using a `VideoView`.  I would like to know the orientation of the video that was captured.

I don't want to use the orientation at the time of the intent call because the user may rotate the device prior to hitting the shutter button.  I also don't want to implement my own custom video capture.

Is the orientation of the video stored in the saved file and/or returned in the intent result?

Comment: Can't you compare video's height versus width and decide the orientation yourself? I think most of the cameras just record in a single orientation (landscape).

Comment: How could a camera possibly prevent the user from rotating the device?  I would hope that at minimum the capture intent makes note of which direction is up and stores it in the video file's metadata.  There's certainly plenty of use cases for portrait-oriented video (front facing phone camera being a prime example).

Answer (score 13):

> Is the orientation of the video stored in the saved file and/or returned in the intent result?

The AOSP `VideoCamera` activity does supply the rotation value of the camera device to the `MediaRecorder.setOrientationHint()` method. Here's an excerpt of the code in the [`VideoCamera.initializeRecorder()`](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/packages/apps/LegacyCamera/src/com/android/camera/VideoCamera.java) code related to this:

```
    // See android.hardware.Camera.Parameters.setRotation for
    // documentation.
    // Note that mOrientation here is the device orientation, which is 
    // the opposite of what getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation() 
    // would return, which is the orientation the graphics need to rotate 
    // in order to render correctly.
    int rotation = 0;
    if (mOrientation != OrientationEventListener.ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) {
        CameraInfo info = CameraHolder.instance().getCameraInfo()[mCameraId];
        if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            rotation = (info.orientation - mOrientation + 360) % 360;
        } else {  // back-facing camera
            rotation = (info.orientation + mOrientation) % 360;
        }
    }
    mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(rotation);
```

Here's the documentation for [`setOrientationHint()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setOrientationHint%28int%29) explaining the storage of the information:

> Sets the orientation hint for output video playback. This method
>   should be called before prepare(). This method will not trigger the
>   source video frame to rotate during video recording, but to add a
>   composition matrix containing the rotation angle in the output video
>   if the output format is OutputFormat.THREE_GPP or OutputFormat.MPEG_4
>   so that a video player can choose the proper orientation for playback.
>   Note that some video players may choose to ignore the compostion
>   matrix in a video during playback.

Since you are using the framework's `VideoView` widget to playback the video, it should already handle the information in the composition matrix correctly and you should only need to compare the width and height of the video to decide whether to set a landscape or portrait orientation for your playback activity. One simple way to do this would be to just call [`ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html#createVideoThumbnail%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) (which internally uses `MediaMetaDataRetriever`) and check the resolution of the returned bitmap.

Comment: I am surprised that the `VideoView` doesn't default to playing the video in line with the current layout's orientation.  I.e., if the `VideoView` is playing back a landscape video while the current layout is in portrait orientation, the video would be "letterboxed" and still played in portrait orientation such that video "up" correctly points upward without rotating the screen.

Comment: I am using same method but how to get mOrientation value as i am getting info.oreintation value same .FYI I am capturing video in landscape fixed orientation

Answer (score 4):

Similar to how al. suggested in his answer, I use the `MediaMetadataRetriever` but with the `METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION` key:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource( absoluteVideoFilePath );
String orientation = mediaMetadataRetriever.extractMetadata(
         MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION );
```

I checked capturing video with all 4 different orientations of the front camera, and the metadata is always different.
Note: `METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION` needs API Level 17 or above.

Comment: Yeah you have to be careful with this one, because the `METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION` key has only been available since API Level 17.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MediaMetadataRetriever to get the width and height of your video and figure out the orientation prior to loading it.

Comment: Do you have evidence that these are swapped when recorded using a different orientation?

Comment: No, I don't have evidence. I can tell you that even in the android framework (eg Navigation bar), screen width is compared to height to get the orientation. Is there a reason you can't test this yourself? Should be relatively quick.

Comment: Yes, short of another answer, I will check this out.  I did find out that ffmpeg can check the orientation flag--though that is certainly a much heavier weight answer than yours, if it works.

Comment: For anyone reading this now, the width and height will not be swapped. It will always seem to be a landscape video.