# Android Front Camera recording video but plays upside down...!

Tags: android, orientation, android-camera, landscape, screen-rotation

I have managed to create an android application to record videos but the problem is with the orientation of front camera video . The output is not the as per requirements . It gets automatically rotated .

Application orientation is landscape . So, I need to record using front cam in landscape mode.

Nothing is working out .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look at how the AOSP [VideoCamera activity](http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/packages/apps/LegacyCamera/src/com/android/camera/VideoCamera.java) is implementing this:

```
    if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        rotation = (info.orientation - mOrientation + 360) % 360;
    } else {  // back-facing camera
        rotation = (info.orientation + mOrientation) % 360;
    }
```

There are some more details in [my answer for another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12417965/1023092).

Comment: im trying to use 
`mrec.setOrientationHint(0);`
in  `private void startRecording()` function but it dosen't allow me to start the video

Comment: what is mOrientation?? and could you provide the full code? i am trying to reslove it from past two days

Comment: @RahulKhurana, I updated the stale omapzoom link to androidxref so you can look at the full code.

Comment: Hi thanks for your code but i ended up with [afollestad's material-camera](https://www.github.com/afollestad/material-camera) library on github, because i was getting late but i will surely look into your code

Answer (score 1):

Add this where you start you video recording below setVideoSource

```
mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
if (cameraId == 1) {
    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile
        .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));
    mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(270);
} else if (cameraId == 0) {
    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile
        .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
    mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
}
```

`mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(270);` is for front camera upside down issue

Comment: I tried. but it just create the mirror image of the video.

Answer (score 0):

Check the camera ID, if it is 1 then follow the orientation change for media player "setOrientationHit()

```
private static final SparseIntArray REAR_ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();
static {
    REAR_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 270);
    REAR_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 0);
    REAR_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 90);
    REAR_ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 180);
}
```

Then in media player preview preparing methods as :

```
if(cameraId == FRONT_CAMERA) {
     mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(REAR_ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation));
}
```